# Positive integer solutions of $x^2-1 = y^p$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, diophantine-equations

Let $x,y$ be two positive integers such that $x^2-1=y^p$ where $p$ is a prime. Find all possible $x,y,p$

I tried using Lifting the Exponent Lemma or considering the smallest prime that divides $x$ or that divides $y$ and tried solving. 
I think that $(x,y,p)=(3,2,3)$ is the only solution but there might be some more.

Instead of providing a full solution, may I get some hint at first? If I still can't solve, I'll post my methods I tried using the provided hint and then request for a full solution.

Comment: Where are $a,b$ ?

Comment: @AtulMishra typo, likely $a=x,b=y$

Comment: Fixed all typos

Comment: The [Catalan Conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan%27s_conjecture), now known as Mihăilescu's theorem shows that $8,9$ are the only consecutive perfect powers .

Comment: @lulu Yeah but that's too heavy for an elementary number theory Olympiad problem.

Comment: Even for $p=3$ the problem isn't trivial...though as it is an example of a Mordell Curve, standard elliptic curve theory suffices.  I am surprised to learn that there is meant to be some "easy" way to handle all the prime $p$. What is the source of this problem?

Comment: @lulu Someone posted this in AoPS (Art of Problem Solving)

Comment: Please edit your question to include the link to the original source.  To be sure, the fact that someone said it was readily solvable does not make it so.

Comment: @lulu It's not easy to find the problem there. AoPS has a huge number of forums/threads, so, it's not possible to find where it is posted. Had I known that, I could've easily posted in the AoPS forum, instead of MSE. I'm sorry for that.

Comment: Well...using Catalan we know that $x=3,y=2,p=3$ is the only solution.  If you could magically show this was the only solution for prime $p$ then that would imply the full theorem (as a counterexample with exponent $m$ would give us a counterexample with exponent $p$ for each prime dividing $m$, so unless I am missing something I don't see how this special case is easier than the whole.

Comment: Well here we are only dealing with the exponent $2$ on $x$, so it is not immediately the general theorem either.

Comment: @TobErnack Do you agree it's solvable without Catalan?

Comment: I do not know if the full case is easily solvable, but I think showing that $y$ is even can be done in elementary ways.

Comment: @Mathbg, which Olympiad?

Answer (score 3):

Here is a partial answer showing there are no solutions if $y$ is odd.
I leave part of it in spoiler tags since the OP wanted hints.

We have $x^2 - 1 = y^p$ and so $(x + 1)(x - 1) = y^p$.
First assume that $y$ is odd.

We have $\gcd(x + 1, x - 1) \mid 2$, and since $y$ is odd, that means $x$ is even and thus $x \pm 1$ is odd. So they are coprime.

By the fact that $\mathbb{Z}$ is a UFD, this forces $x + 1 = m^p$ and $x - 1 = n^p$ for some positive integers $m, n$.

> Thus $2 = m^p - n^p = (m - n)(m^{p-1}n + \ldots + m^2n^{p-2} + mn^{p-1})$.
>
> This means $m = n + 1$ or $m = n + 2$.
>
> In the first case we have $(n + 1)^p - n^p = 2$ which is impossible since the left side is odd.
>
> In the second case we have $(n + 2)^p - n^p = 2$ which has unique solution $n = 1, p = 1$ but $1$ is not prime so this does not count. Note that the solution is unique because the LHS is an increasing function of both $n$ and $p$.
>
> So there are no solutions with $y$ odd.

Comment: I am not sure if the subtraction method will work as easily for this case, because the factor of $2^{p - 1}$ might mess with things (I was using the fact that differences of perfect $p$-th powers factor nicely).

Comment: My reasoning doesn't make sense. Hence, removed it. Now, how shall we proceed?

Comment: How shall I proceed for the $y=\text{even}$ case?

Comment: @Mathbg I don't think there is an elementary way to solve your equation in the case when $y$ is even.

Comment: @Xam One of my friends have solve it. And I have posted the answer below.